# jqplot legend control per series. Series showLabel not working with EnhancedLegendRenderer

Tags: jqplot, legend, series

I wish to selectively hide legends of some serie in a plot. And this http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.showLabel looks to be the correct option for this.

But using `series:{showLabel:false}` with doesn't seem to work.

An open(old) ticket in this regard : https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/100/feature-request-individual-legend-control

Am I using it right? Any other workarounds to achieve this is also appreciated.

**Update:**

`showLabel` works fine with normal legendRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `draw` function in the file `jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.js` we see this at about line 132:

```
if (idx < series.length && (series[idx].show || series[idx].showLabel)){
```

For context, this bit of code is part of the functionality that creates the legend table. A row is created if either the series is set to be shown (default is `true`) or the series label is to be show. This means that to prevent a legend item being created for a series, you would need to hide the entire series itself, as well as setting `showLabel` to `false`, which isn't ideal.

Instead, try setting the `||` to `&&` - this worked in my case. Try making the change on the unminified version first.

**Edit:**

First thing to do is to make the change I suggested in my original answer.

Next, we need to prevent the `tr` elements in the legend from being created if `showLabel` is `false`. Just prior to the if-statement mentioned above, you will see this code:

```
tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
tr.addClass('jqplot-table-legend');
if (reverse){
    tr.prependTo(this._elem);
}
else{
    tr.appendTo(this._elem);
}
```

Change it to this (all we are doing here is wrapping it in the same if-statement we used before):

```
if (idx < series.length && (series[idx].show && series[idx].showLabel)){
    tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.addClass('jqplot-table-legend');
    if (reverse){
        tr.prependTo(this._elem);
    }
    else{
        tr.appendTo(this._elem);
    }
}
```

Scroll down some more (about line 212) and you will see the following code:

```
if (this.showLabels)  {
    console.log(this._elem.find('tr').length - 1);
    td2.bind('click', {series:s, speed:speed, plot: plot, replot:this.seriesToggleReplot }, handleToggle);
    td2.addClass('jqplot-seriesToggle');
}
```

This is binding the event handler for when one of the series is clicked in the legend. What we need to do is add an additional property to the object literal that encapsulates the data that is passed to the `click` method:

```
td2.bind('click', {series:s, speed:speed, plot: plot,
    replot:this.seriesToggleReplot,
    trIndex: this._elem.find('tr').length - 1 }, handleToggle);
```

`trIndex` represents the actual index of the row in the HTML table. It is this that ensures the legend will strike off the correct element.

Inside the `doLegendToggle` declaration, you will see code like this:

```
if (s.canvas._elem.is(':hidden') || !s.show) {
    // Not sure if there is a better way to check for showSwatches and showLabels === true.
    // Test for "undefined" since default values for both showSwatches and showLables is true.
    if (typeof plot.options.legend.showSwatches === 'undefined' || plot.options.legend.showSwatches === true) {
        plot.legend._elem.find('td').eq(sidx * 2).addClass('jqplot-series-hidden');
    }
    if (typeof plot.options.legend.showLabels === 'undefined' || plot.options.legend.showLabels === true) {
        plot.legend._elem.find('td').eq((sidx * 2) + 1).addClass('jqplot-series-hidden');
    }
}
else {
    if (typeof plot.options.legend.showSwatches === 'undefined' || plot.options.legend.showSwatches === true) {
        plot.legend._elem.find('td').eq(sidx * 2).removeClass('jqplot-series-hidden');
    }
    if (typeof plot.options.legend.showLabels === 'undefined' || plot.options.legend.showLabels === true) {
        plot.legend._elem.find('td').eq((sidx * 2) + 1).removeClass('jqplot-series-hidden');
    }
}
```

See those four references to the `sidx` variable, change them so that the code is instead using the `trIndex` variable. To do this, replace the four `sidx` references with `d.trIndex`.

Comment: I had tried this exact same thing soon after posting the question. But the problem is, this doesn't bode well with the seriesToggle option ie., clicking on one of visible legend labels strikes off the other ones or so. So I guess that part of the code must also be altered to fit this.

Comment: @Siva Good point. See my edit. It's fairly complicated, but it worked for me.

Comment: Looks good to me! Perhaps you could send a pull request to [jqplot repo](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot) so others can take a look as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line below your jqplot:

```
$($("#chartXXX .jqplot-table-legend").get(0)).hide();
```

Play around with the number inside get(), as I am not exactly sure how the number is mapped to the legend elements. This solution is much more elegant than changing the enhancedLegendRenderer code.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed it for my code to:

    $("#chartXXX tr.jqplot-table-legend").first().hide();

To hide the first table row (first legend entry).

Answer (score 0):

Well I combined answer from jbass and from DaFrenk and the result is:

```
$($("#chartXXX tr.jqplot-table-legend").get(0)).hide();
```

The number in `get` is zero based index which defines row in legend table. This does exactly  what I want.